# cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails laravel

Tags: laravel, chave-estrangeira

Galera estou com este erro em meu sistem laravel:

```
cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails laravel
```

Ele informe que o ID não existe, só que ele existe. Mesmo quando tento realizar a inserção manualmente este erro é apresentado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa mensagem não é de ID inexistente, mas sim da ligação com outra tabela, provavelmente seu insert depende de outra coisa, tem que ver qual tabela esta exigindo isso, sem detalhes de todas tabelas e do insert que você fez não tem nem como adivinharmos aonde esta o erro. Esse erro não é com Laravel, mas sim com tua estrutura do banco ou com teu insert.

Comment: Inseri, desculpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da um select na sua tabela tbl_respostas e veja se os campos pesquisa_id, pergunta_id e opcao_id não estão com valor 0.

Caso sim altera para nulo e tenta novamente.

Comment: Obrigado, descobri, eu comi bola, pois já estou inserindo o opção_id e não precisava de uma relação.